# community cloud record detail page of Contact not showing quick actions( Email , Log A Call , New Task , New Event)

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-experience

In Community Cloud for record detail page , i have used "Record Information Tabs"  component which display Details, Related and Feed tabs.

For Case object Under the feed tab all activities(Post,Log A Call...) added to layout are visible.

[image]

But for *Contact object* activities ****Email, Log A Call, New Task and New Event added to layout are not visible in communities****.

[image]

Can some please help me to understand what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think in your Community Contact Detail Record Information Component , you choose only 3 Tabs, Record Details, Related Records, Feed, you should choose 4th tab (Activity Time line) also for Activities, like below image . in your Case record detail it might be other way.
[image]